# Regex returning no matches for this syntax

Tags: regex

I was wondering if you could advise, i have scoured mostly your site for similar examples but as programmers your answers seem very complex to someone like me who is a beginner to this sort of thing

Basically we have a file name structure which has a minimum of 5 characters and a maximum of 6 and starts with either `1` or `2`, then preceded by a full stop `.` then only a number between 1 and 5 after the `.`

An example file name is is below

> 123456.1

I am trying to create a regex which will pick out the correct filename as per the statement above when ran against a text file list, however i have tried this and it does not work

If I try without `1|2` it picks up the reference but I need the first digit to be `1` or `2`

```
^1|2\d{5,6}][\.][0-5]{1}$
```

Hoping for this to pick out from a text file any digit that starts with a `1` or `2` and minimum of 5 and max of 6 digits with a full stop after then followed by another number

Basically some examples i want it to pick out are below:

```
123456.1  OK
25689.2   OK
061589.2  NOT OK
1235.6    NOT OK
765812.1  NOT OK
289657.5  OK
```

I hope i have provided enough info, let me know if not.

Comment: The first problem I see that's immediately apparent is that you do not have your `(` and `)` around your OR `|` statement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`^[12]\d{4,5}\.[1-5]$` should work.

Short explanation:

- `[12]` matches either a 1 or a 2
- `\d{4,5}` matches any sequence of (any) digits with a length of min 4 and max 5 (because we already matched the first digit with `[12]` before)
- `\.` matches a period
- `[1-5]` matches any digit between 1 and 5

Comment: I think you meant it to be `[0-5]` if I read the question correctly?

Comment: +1 to the answer. @J-Law *then only a number **between 1 and 5***

Comment: You're right. The original RegEx was throwing me off. Didn't read it closely, obviously.

Comment: Hi many thanks for your responses, I shall try this out once back in the office Friday morning,cannot believe the rapid response

Answer (score 0):

If you're actually validating numbers, why not actually validate numbers? (This answer may be slightly stunty)

```
  class Program
    {
        private static readonly string[] Items =
        {
            "123456.1",
            "25689.2",
            "061589.2", //NOT
            "1235.6", //NOT
            "765812.1", //NOT
            "289657.5"
        };
        static void Main()
        {
             foreach (string item in Items)
             {
                 Console.WriteLine(Validate(item));
             }
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
        static bool Validate (string item)
        {
            decimal d;
            if (decimal.TryParse(item,out d))
            {
                if (((d < 10000.1m) || (d > 299999.5m)) ||
                    ((d > 29999.5m) &&  (d < 100000.1m))) return false;
                // validate fraction here
                var i = d - decimal.Truncate(d);
                return (i >= 0.1m && i <= 0.5m);
            } 
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your comment, however the one line regexpression I use above is incorporated into a powershell script and which I find straight forward to run powershell queries against, the powershell script extracts the match of the regexpression from a text file so found this the easiest solution. Thanks again

Comment: That's awesome! If you liked @speakr 's answer, please mark your question answered.

Comment: Hiya, I'm sure I will do, I'm not in the office now until Friday, once tried and tested I will mark as answer then this can be used for others who may find this useful.

Comment: Such is the circle of life, my friend.